# undefined reference to regcomp

Tags: c, regex, stm32

I'm developing stm32 with SW4STM32.
When I tried to use arm-none-eabi\include\regex.h, I included  and compiled.
And then I got a strange things.
regex.h defined various canstant, for example

```
#define REG_NOMATCH  1
#define REG_BADPAT   2
#define REG_ECOLLATE 3
#define REG_ECTYPE   4
```

and voarious struct,

```
typedef struct {
    int re_magic;
    size_t re_nsub;     /* number of parenthesized subexpressions */
    __const char *re_endp;  /* end pointer for REG_PEND */
    struct re_guts *re_g;   /* none of your business :-) */
} regex_t;
```

and some function, including

```
int regcomp(regex_t *__restrict, const char *__restrict, int);
size_t  regerror(int, const regex_t *__restrict, char *__restrict, size_t);
int regexec(const regex_t *__restrict, const char *__restrict,
            size_t, regmatch_t [__restrict], int);
void    regfree(regex_t *);
```

The following is my code

```
u8 Is_REG_Match(char* reg,char* s){

u8 z=0;
u8 z1=0;
regex_t reg_temp;

z=regcomp(&reg_temp,reg,0);
regcomp(&reg_temp, reg , 0);
if(z==0){
z1=regexec(&reg_temp,s,0,NULL,0);
regfree(&reg_temp);
return z1;
}
else
return 200;
```

}

and when I compiled, reg_temp is good, but function regcomp, regexec and regfree was error--undefined reference to 'regcomp',etc.

The regex.h is definitely compiled, as I try to delete the define of struct regex_t in regex.h and

```
regex_t reg_temp;
```

become error.

It seems like the regex.h is compiled not completely, just missing the function part.
How can I fix it?

Comment: It seems that there is no lib file. So even though I include regex.h and try to use regcomp(), but there is no lib, the reference of regcomp is still undefined.

Comment: I find that regcomp() and so on is the function in libc.a, which is automatically linked while compiling...So why it shows undefined?

Comment: In regex.h there is only declaration of regcomp. You are probably missing regex.c.

Answer (score 1):

Your need to link the regex libraries.

for gcc, mingW:
add -lregex to makefile, then will link to the libsystre-0.so

If you want static link, add -Wl,-Bstatic -lregex -ltre -lintl -liconv to makefile.